# Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set / multiple databases

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Spring boot application.  I have this data source:

```
package _ourapp_.vTiger

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import javax.sql.DataSource

@Configuration
@Component("_ourapp_.vTiger")
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = ["_ourapp_.vTiger"],
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "vTigerEntityManager",
    transactionManagerRef = "vTigerTransactionManager"
)
open class DataSource {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "database.vtiger")
    open fun calldata_base(): DataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create().build()

    @Bean
    open fun vTigerEntityManager(): LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean =
        (LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean()).apply {
            dataSource = calldata_base()
            setPackagesToScan("_ourapp_.vTiger.model")
            jpaVendorAdapter = HibernateJpaVendorAdapter()
        }

    @Bean
    open fun vTigerTransactionManager() = JpaTransactionManager(vTigerEntityManager().`object`!!)
}
```

and in application.properties:

```
database.vtiger.jdbc-url=jdbc:mariadb://_ourdatabaseinstance_.rds.amazonaws.com:3306
database.vtiger.user=_ourname_
database.vtiger.username=_ourname_
database.vtiger.password=_ourpass_
database.vtiger.maximum-pool-size=5
database.vtiger.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
database.vtiger.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
database.vtiger.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
```

because our application has another database, omitted here for simplicity.

It is connecting to an AWS Aurora instance, engine version **5.6.mysql_aurora.1.22.5**

Application startup fails with multiple messages including

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'vTigerEntityManager' defined in class path resource [au/com/ngv/kitten/vTiger/DataSource.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
```

(which is why I quoted the particular source above, since `vTigerEntityManager` is defined therein) but finally the dreaded

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

I'm using MariaDB because the IntelliJ database connection tool recommended it over the MySQL driver.

How can hibernate.dialect be 'not set' when it clearly **is** set in application.properties?

In case it's relevant, I'm using [this workaround](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-13313?_ga=2.147993854.853513815.1652062931-1296835606.1644292027) in IntelliJ itself.  The error occurs when I run the application within IntelliJ.

Comment: For me, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63283846/issue-integrating-mariadb-client-with-mysql-db) turns out to be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right variable to set in application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but my `application.properties` has the line

    `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect`

and I'm still getting the _'hibernate.dialect' not set_ error.

Comment: From the code you included above, I see you used:
`hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect`

Comment: Yes, `hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect` was wrong but until I'd incorporated that fix/workaround for the broken AWS implementation, no _application.properties_ tweaking was going to solve the problem.  I would upvote but lack the 'reputation'.

Comment: @YounesEl-karama using that property will only work if you are connecting to a single database or to multiple databases of same vendor.  How would you set it if you had to connect to 2 different vendors?  For example Oracle and DB2?